# Chrome Developer Console Started Logging Too Much Info. CSS Warnings

Tags: css, google-chrome, logging, console, developer-tools

I do a large part of my development work in the Chrome developer console, and love it, but recently something highly annoying has happened.

Every page load, I now get a log of every CSS property warning, a considerable list that fills the entire console with warnings. I know I can set the log level to filter out warnings, but I want to see some warnings, particularly script related.  Also, this resets itself every page load, so all the CSS warnings fill up my console, and look visually upsetting.

See the screenshot:

[image: console]

I believe that this started happening immediately following the most recent chrome update, but I was also fooling around with some of the settings in the console.  I've looked through the settings in the console and under `chrome://flags` but haven't found anything.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Those look like warnings, so you could just select "Errors" instead of "All"

Comment: You didn't read my whole post.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with:
        <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black; transform-origin: 20px;"></div>

Answer (score 1):

I've never had this happen to me, but have you tried deleting the history?

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts#console

Comment: That works for the moment, but on the next page load, it repeats.